Identity server redirection problems on the same browser instance
I have a problem when I use many account in the same instance of browser.
In the first connection from my site to the client site, the authorize endpoint is invoking, and I have in the log: "No user present in authorize request". So, I have been redirect to the login page.
It's normal for the first time. I enter the login/password, and the session is created, and I have been redirect to the client site, to the correct account.
When I decide to logout from the account and use another account in my site, when connecting to the client site, the authorize endpoint is invoking, but now I have in the log: "User in authorize request: {subjectId}", the same subject id of the user before. So I have been redirected to the client site, but to the wrong account (account of the previous user).
I am using Identity server 8. How can I resolve this?
Thank you

To deal with this you need to tell the authorization server that you want a new user to sign in. Do so by including the Open ID Connect prompt=login parameter in your authorization request.
